# Annoying small images in signatures as mail attachments in OSX Mail

Tags: macos, email, attachments, email-signature

How not to treat those small signature images (logos, etc.) as mail attachments? I usually want to identify a recent email with attachment, but most emails show up with many attachments. This is also the case when I search mails with attachments and I get tons of results.

Is there a way (preferences or using plug-ins) to ignore small image attachments?

An organization which is committed to informing people not to use attached images in signatures is also accepted ^_^

Comment: [Welcome to email hell](http://superuser.com/questions/259918/in-2011-what-are-the-reasons-to-stick-with-plain-text-mails/259928#259928).

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late with this answer, but the answer is to upload the images somewhere online and then insert them from the remote URL rather than as an attachment. How do you even do an image attachment in an email signature in Mail anyway? I only know how to use a remote image. (You have to create an html page that references the image and then view the page in a browser and then copy and paste the image from the browser into the signature entry box in Mail.)

Comment: Question is not about sending an email with signature. You have no control over how other people do it. I think it's more common in corporate emails. Thanks anyway.